# Is instantaneous velocity a scalar or a vector?

Tags: velocity, vectors

So this is a simple question that I have been confused about.  Last night I was in a discussion with a friend, and we somehow ended up on this topic.

1. He believes that instantaneous velocity is a scalar as it has no direction.
2. I believe that time counts as a direction (though chances are I am wrong). So in simple velocity (lets say $m/s$) does time count as a direction?

Comment: What do you mean by *instantaneous velocity*? I'm guessing this means the velocity at a specific point in time, in which case that's just *velocity*, and it is a vector.

Comment: You are correct, that is what I ment by instantaneous velocity.

Comment: @JohnRennie In intro courses, instantaneous velocity is often used to differentiate it from average velocity. It highlights the fact that a limit is being taken, something that's new for most of those learners.

Comment: [This question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59782/) might help you.

Comment: Also related is the question [How can there be really any instantaneous velocity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116955/)

Comment: It is common in physics to call "speed" to the modulus (a scalar) of the velocity (a vector). and the answer to "does time count as a direction?" is no.

Comment: I get the impression that OP's question (v1) is asking about kinematics in 1D rather than 3D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a vector.

Instantaneous velocity $\vec v$ is defined as

$$\vec v \equiv \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta \vec r}{\Delta t}.$$

In that equation, $\Delta \vec r$ is the displacement that occurs during time interval $\Delta t$. Putting on my math hat for physicists, the numerator is a vector, and the denominator is a scalar, so the resulting quantity $\Delta \vec r / \Delta t$ is a vector as well. Taking the limit $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ doesn't change the type of quantity that $\Delta \vec r / \Delta t$ is.

The fact that "time has a direction" as you pointed out is not correct in regards to what type of quantity velocity is. The vector nature comes from the $\Delta \vec r$ bit.